# Adding PyDev to Eclipse using the PyDev zip

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm having a lot of trouble getting Eclipse to recognise PyDev when using the PyDev zip file. (I need to use the zip file as the Dev machine does not have internet access).

I have Eclipse installed and have downloaded the PyDev zip. I've Googled a fair bit and tried the following based on suggestions I found:-

1. Unzipped the .zip into ECLIPSE/helios/dropins and restarted eclipse.
2. Unzipped the .zip into ECLIPSE/helios/plugins and restarted eclipse.

Neither makes Python appear as a selection in the Eclipse, Window, Preferences.

Helios contains the executable eclipse file I use to load eclipse.

I'm using eclipse in Redhat linux.

One suggestion was to extract the zip over the eclipse plugins and features folders, but I don't see how that would work as the zip just produces a heap of files and no folders.

Any help to get this working would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Just unzipping the Pydev zip file under C:\eclipse\dropins should be enough. So:

```
1) Unzip the zip file in C:\eclipse\dropins
2) Launch Eclipse
3) Test your installation: Go to Window -> Preferences -> PyDev
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did this today and a far easier way to do it is to use the built-in installer. Go to Help -> Install New Software and then type pydev in the software filter. Since you already have the zip, if you extract it in the dropins folder, you'll skip the download portion and go straight to installing it.

I have been able to use the zip to install it manually before. I would extract its contents in the eclipse folder overwriting the features and plugins folder. I suggested this to a coworker earlier today and it didn't work for her. She had to download the newest version of eclipse for this method to work. She downloaded the classic version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found the unzip method I was using was incorrect (should read the man page properly) where I added -j. When I unzip the file correctly it fall out into the plugins and features folders. Though unfortunately when I extract it into the eclipse plugins and features folders it still doesn't appear in eclipse. I also tried your suggestion of fully extracting into dropins and Install New Software, but it doesn't see it. Do I just add the dropins folder as the Work With: entry and PyDev as the filter?

Comment: If you set Work With to All Available Sites it should pick it up.

Comment: Solved it. Was simply to use the "PyDev 2.2.1-sources.zip" instead of the "PyDev 2.2.1.zip". Did a straight "unzip PyDev 2.2.1-sources.zip" in the helios folder where both the "plugins" and "features" folders are located and made sure all the extracted files had the same ownership as Eclipse. Stated Eclipse and there it was in Preferences. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Damn it! Spoke too soon. PyDev appears in Preferences, but when I actually choose any of the options under PyDev e.g. Interpreter - Python i get a Problem Occurred error message saying: Unable to create the selected preference page. An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.python.pydev (833). Help!

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with PyDev and Eclipse. Reinstalled Eclipse on a fresh machine and unzipped the standard PyDev over it (not the source version) and it worked fine. Did the same thing on the same machine having the problems but in a different location (/home) also worked fine. So it looks like a configuration problem on the machine not a PyDev/Eclipse issue. Sorry for the run around and thanks for the help. Dog.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever it's worth, I was having the same problem running eclipse 3.6 on RHEL 6. When I ran eclipse as myself, I didn't get any PyDev options; however, when I ran eclipse as root, everything showed up. So permissions could be an issue fyi.

Comment: It is generally a good idea to post a new question yourself rather than adding an answer which really is another question. Also, when you get a few rep points under your belt you will be able to post comments - which in turn often do ask for more information or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Open the eclipse and navigate in the below format of the menu bar of the eclispe

Window > Perspective > Open Perspective and select Pydev. As a result when next time you open eclipse you will be using it with python.Please follow the below screen shot in the link I am Using python 3.7 with eclipse photon ide.

[Eclispe with Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMpOi.png)